# jQuery scrolling marquee in html page title tag

Tags: jquery, tags, scroll, title, marquee

I want to place a scrolling marquee in my html title tag using jquery but don't know how and can't seem to find a good explanation online anywhere.  Can someone help me please?

Comment: He's talking about the HTML <title> tag... not an actual <marquee> tag nor actually moving from left or right. He's talking about how the HTML title tags appear to be moving left or right by removing and adding characters to the <title>.

Comment: On another note @sadmicrowave why in God's name would you want to do this?

Comment: hahaha, ok, either way... is there a way to prevent answers that would have been asked back in the browser war days ;)

Comment: While this is certainly something you can do, I'd recommend not doing it from a usability perspective.  It's distracting to the user and causes them to focus on the title rather than focusing on the content of your page.

Comment: Yeah, seriously, please don't unless you're making a site that is supposed to look awful: http://www.angelfire.com/super/badwebs/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's not very hard to do if you just want it to scroll like the `marquee` tag:

```
(function titleMarquee() {
    document.title = document.title.substring(1)+document.title.substring(0,1);
    setTimeout(titleMarquee, 200);
})();
```

That's pretty basic but should give you an idea on how to tweak it to your liking.

Comment: Thanks for the code.. it works well except for one hitch. After the first scroll, for some reason all of the spaces are removed and the words are crunched up next to each other. How can I preserve the spaces? Thanks, Phil

Comment: @psarid I've posted an answer to fix that hitch.

Answer (score 6):

In Tatu Ulmanen's answer, there is a problem with space characters. As psarid stated as comment, after the first scroll, all of the spaces are removed.

This is because html parser trims texts. That means it removes the spaces at the end and at the beginning of the text. When title is scrolling, the title object in html looks like that:

```
<title>Scrolling Title With Spaces</title>
<title>crolling Title With SpacesS</title>
<title>rolling Title With SpacesSc</title>
<title>olling Title With SpacesScr</title>
...
<title>Title With SpacesScrolling</title>
```

As you can see above, we lost the space between words `Scrolling` and `Spaces`. To prevent that, we need to store original `document.title` somewhere in our javascript code and put a space or something else to the end of it. Then, we can scroll `document.title` by scrolling the text in the other variable. Here is the modified code of Tatu Ulmanen.

```
var documentTitle = document.title + " - ";

(function titleMarquee() {
    document.title = documentTitle = documentTitle.substring(1) + documentTitle.substring(0,1);
    setTimeout(titleMarquee, 200);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below script on your page head and then call the scrlsts() function on body onload

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var scrl = $('title').text();
function scrlsts() {
     scrl = scrl.substring(1, scrl.length) + scrl.substring(0, 1);
     document.title = scrl;
     setTimeout("scrlsts()", 500);
     }
<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

No jQuery:

```
setInterval(function () {
  $("head title").html($("head title").html().substring(1) + $("head title").html().substring(0,1));
}, 300);
```