# Split JavaScript string into array of codepoints? (taking into account "surrogate pairs" but not "grapheme clusters")

Tags: javascript, string, unicode, codepoint, surrogate-pairs

Splitting a JavaScript string into "characters" can be done trivially but there are problems if you care about Unicode (and you should care about Unicode).

JavaScript natively treats characters as 16-bit entities ([UCS-2 or UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16)) but this does not allow for Unicode characters outside the [BMP (Basic Multilingual Plane)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Basic_Multilingual_Plane).

To deal with Unicode characters beyond the BMP, JavaScript must take into account "[surrogate pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/surrogate-pairs)", which it does not do natively.

**I'm looking for how to split a js string by codepoint, whether the codepoints require one or two JavaScript "characters" (code units).**

Depending on your needs, splitting by [codepoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) might not be enough, and you might want to split by "[grapheme cluster](http://www.termwiki.com/EN:grapheme_cluster)", where a cluster is a base codepoint followed by all its non-spacing modifier codepoints, such as [combining accents and diacritics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character).

**For the purposes of this question I do not require splitting by grapheme cluster.**

Answer (score 44, accepted):

@bobince's answer has (luckily) become a bit dated; you can now simply use

```
var chars = Array.from( text )
```

to obtain a list of single-codepoint strings which does respect astral / 32bit / surrogate Unicode characters.

Comment: Or `const chars = [...text];`. Both use iteration under the covers.

Answer (score 14):

Along the lines of @John Frazer's answer, one can use this even succincter form of string iteration:

```
const chars = [...text]
```

e.g., with:

```
const text = 'A\uD835\uDC68B\uD835\uDC69C\uD835\uDC6A'
const chars = [...text] // ["A", "", "B", "", "C", ""]
```

Comment: best answer, if you like succinctness.

Comment: this also works where the actual graphic symbols are pasted into the string (if your IDE supports that)

Answer (score 5):

In ECMAScript 6 you'll be able to use a string as an iterator to get code points, or you could search a string for `/./ug`, or you could call `getCodePointAt(i)` repeatedly.

Unfortunately `for`..`of` syntax and regexp flags can't be polyfilled and calling a polyfilled `getCodePoint()` would be super slow (O(n²)), so we can't realistically use this approach for a while yet.

So doing it the manual way:

```
String.prototype.toCodePoints= function() {
    chars = [];
    for (var i= 0; i<this.length; i++) {
        var c1= this.charCodeAt(i);
        if (c1>=0xD800 && c1<0xDC00 && i+1<this.length) {
            var c2= this.charCodeAt(i+1);
            if (c2>=0xDC00 && c2<0xE000) {
                chars.push(0x10000 + ((c1-0xD800)<<10) + (c2-0xDC00));
                i++;
                continue;
            }
        }
        chars.push(c1);
    }
    return chars;
}
```

For the inverse to this see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3759300/18936

Comment: `getCodePointAt` is `O(n)`. The argument it accepts is not the codepoint index but the code unit index (the regular String index).

Comment: @glebm did you mean that `getCodePointAt` is `O(1)`?

Comment: Yes, `O(1)`, I can't edit the comment anymore

Answer (score 1):

Another method using codePointAt:

```
String.prototype.toCodePoints = function () {
  var arCP = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i += 1) {
    var cP = this.codePointAt(i);
    arCP.push(cP);
    if (cP >= 0x10000) {
      i += 1;
    }
  }
  return arCP;
}
```