# How to iterate over only the characters in a string I can actually see?

Tags: javascript, unicode, surrogate-pairs, astral-plane

Normally I would just use something like `str[i]`.

But what if `str = "☀️"`?

`str[i]` fails. `for (x of str) console.log(x)` also fails. It prints out a total of 4 characters, even though there are clearly only 2 emoji in the string.

What's the best way to iterate over every character I can see in a string (and newlines, I guess), and nothing else?

**The ideal solution would return an array of 2 characters: the 2 emoji, and nothing else.** The claimed duplicate, and a bunch of other solutions I've found, don't fit this criteria.

Comment: I think you should check this blog post : [link](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split JavaScript string into array of codepoints? (taking into account "surrogate pairs" but not "grapheme clusters")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397316/split-javascript-string-into-array-of-codepoints-taking-into-account-surrogat)

Comment: Are you saying you want to capture the emoji, or skip over it and find the next "normal" character?

Comment: @RaymondChen your suggested answer appears to be a polyfill for the `for...of` syntax which I pointed out does not work in this case. But please correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: @KevBot I would like to capture the emoji as a single character. Essentially **if I can select it as a single character, I'd like to capture it as a single character.**

Comment: The suggested answer says "`for..of` cannot be polyfilled." The suggested answers shows how to split a string into code points. If you don't want to polyfill it, then just use it as a free function.

Comment: @RaymondChen My desired answer should **only be 2 characters in length** (both emojis and nothing else). The `toCodePoints` function returns an array of length 4.

Comment: First of all, your original statement is incorrect. the `for  (x in str) console.log(x)` prints six characters (plus additional junk not relevant to the discussion), not the four you originally claimed. That's because the string `"☀️"` is six code units long: `"\u2600\ufe0f\ud83d\ude4c\ud83c\udffc"`. This breaks down into four code points: U+2600 (BLACK SUN WITH RAYS), U+FE0F (VARIANT SELECTOR 16), U+1F64C (PERSON RAISING BOTH HANDS IN CELEBRATION), and U+1F3FC (EMOJI MODIFIER FITZPATRICK TYPE 3). It sounds like you are looking to break into graphemes, which is a harder problem.

Comment: @RaymondChen I said `for (x of str)` not `x in str` specifically because `of` breaks on code points rather than characters. Graphemes turned out to be the magic word here though - once I googled for that I quickly found a decent library to get the job done.

Comment: See my solution posted under a different question that doesn't take Astral characters/Surrogate pairs into account: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966476/javascript-process-each-letter-of-text/36392879#36392879

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your own methods for astral characters.

```
"foobar".match(/[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]|./g);
// => ["f", "o", "o", "", "b", "a", "r"]
```

Comment: This does not work in all cases. Consider `"foob☀️ar".match(/[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]|./g);`.

Comment: @thedayturns: Yeah, I only covered astral characters, which is where JavaScript "mistakenly" splits a single Unicode character into two JS characters. The emptyish string there is a VARIATION SELECTOR 16 (U+FE0F), which is a separate Unicode character, but combines with the previous; a similar issue would be all the combining characters like COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT (U+0301). So to solve *that* problem, you would need a whole library, which is outside the scope of a StackOverflow answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Segmenter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Segmenter) will do what you need:

> The Intl.Segmenter object enables locale-sensitive text segmentation, enabling you to get meaningful items (graphemes, words or sentences) from a string.

In you case, the code would look like this:

```js
const segmenterEmoji = new Intl.Segmenter('en', { granularity: 'word' });
const string2 = '☀️'

const iterator1 = segmenterEmoji.segment(string2)[Symbol.iterator]();

console.log(iterator1.next().value.segment);
// Expected output: '☀️'

console.log(iterator1.next().value.segment);
// Expected output: ''
```

**Note:** The language/locale doesn't really matter in your case because emojis are a little different to "normal text"

In the example from MDN:

```js
const segmenterFr = new Intl.Segmenter('fr', { granularity: 'word' });
const string1 = 'Que ma joie demeure';

const iterator1 = segmenterFr.segment(string1)[Symbol.iterator]();

console.log(iterator1.next().value.segment);
// Expected output: 'Que'

console.log(iterator1.next().value.segment);
// Expected output: ' '
```