# Unicode characters in Angular binding

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unicode

There are some answers on how to display Unicode character codes in Angular bindings, but I'm trying to display one dynamically and everything seems to fail.

I have a component which receives a character code as an `@Input` parameter.

```
<my-component [icon]="e901"></my-component>
```

The component then attempts to show it, but neither of these work:

```
<i>{{ "\u" + icon  }}</i>
<i [innerHTML]="'\u' + icon"</i>
<i [innerHTML]="`\u${icon}`"</i>
<i [innerHTML]="'&#' + icon + ';'"</i>
```

There's a lot of room to play with the syntax but it always either results in an error or just plain displays `\ue901` as a string. It does work if I hardcode the code though:

```
<i>{{ "\ue901" }}</i>
```

It doesn't matter if I generate the string in the template or TypeScript. It doesn't work if I try to pass the entire code as a parameter. Any ideas, guys?

Comment: Not sure if this helps. https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-entity-names/bycodes.html Is it this? http://www.codetable.net/decimal/901

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: This code `&#901;` Try it direct within the `<i></i>` - without the Angular expression syntax `{{ }}`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46959355/495157 `{{"R\u901"}}`

Comment: Oh thanks, this actually works, but in a bit peculiar way!

Comment: Let me know if it works for the binding on `[icon]` as well. That may be harder. because it's normal HTML syntax when you do `&#901;`

Comment: I posted the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After JGFMK pointed out half of the answer, here is the solution:

In the code:

```
this.icon = '&#x' + this.icon + ';';
```

Then in the template:

```
<span [innerHTML]="icon"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use HTML code, here you can search it https://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/html-codes.html

Hope helps

Answer (score 1):

.ts file

```
icon = "\u{1F601}";
```

.html file

```
<p [innerHTML]="icon"></p>
```

Answer (score -4):

Actually it's not possible because you must access pseudo elements with Angular for what you want to achieve.

Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35280118/change-style-of-pseudo-elements-in-angular2) will give you some hints.