# Angular: display unicode characters from API text in innerHTML

Tags: html, json, angular, unicode

API :

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "text": "<p>\r\n    \\u2022\r\n    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit: <br />\r\n    sed do eiusmod <br />\r\n    tempor incididunt ut <br />\r\n    labore et dolore magna aliqua\r\n</p>\r\n<p>\r\n    \\u2022\r\n </p>"
}
```

HTML :

```
<div [innerHTML]="agreementData.text"></div>
```

when I try to display like this Unicode characters like \u2022 display same as \u2022, it doesn't convert in anything, I cant change API I need to handle requests like this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unicode characters in Angular binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54927854/unicode-characters-in-angular-binding)

Comment: when log text in pipe its like this :
<p>
    \u2022
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit: <br />
    sed do eiusmod <br />
    tempor incididunt ut <br />
    labore et dolore magna aliqua
</p>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found solution
pipe:

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'unicodeStringFormat',
})
export class UnicodeFormatPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
        return value.replace(/\\u[\dA-Fa-f]{4}/g, match => {
            return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(match.replace(/\\u/g, ''), 16));
        });;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div [innerHTML]="agreementData.text | unicodeStringFormat"></div>
```