# Scrolling page title in tab with JS

Tags: javascript

I have the title of my webpage set to be the current song playing in an audio player.

Most of the time the song name and artist are much longer than the maximum characters the tab can display.

I am currently displaying the title with:

```
        document.title = (data["track_name"] + " - " + data["artist_name"]);
```

How do I get the title to scroll to show the whole song name and artist?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16354122/how-to-put-scrolling-text-in-title-tag

Comment: Why is everyone in that linked-to thread (and its possible dup thread) using `setTimeout` and recursion? `setInterval` seems like the obvious choice, as it's meant for exactly this sort of thing, and it's simpler to `clearInterval` one interval later, than to keep starting another timeout and `clearTimeout`ing that

Answer (score 2):

You can use `window.setInterval()` to do this.

```
// Start an interval running every 500ms
window.setInterval(function() {
  // Take the first character, and make it the last character
  document.title = document.title.substring(1) + document.title[0];
}, 500);
```

You can add some extra spaces to the end of the title if you want it to wrap a bit longer. e.g. `document.title += ' \xA0 \xA0 \xA0';';`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

Comment: That's why I suggested putting `document.title += '_____ ';` before you set your interval - it'll put some space on the end of it so it doesn't just say 'ng NameSo', but instead 'ng Name_____So' (I used underscores here since SO comments don't like multiple spaces).

Comment: Not working for me.  The title is looking like ArtistTheSongName-Artist, even with document.title += '_____ ';

Comment: When it first starts, it looks perfectly fine. But after the first scroll, its all 1 continuous word.

Comment: Ah - looks like some browsers won't even allow you to programmatically set the title with spaces at the end; parsers will trim the title when building the DOM so that there's no whitespace in a title, but it seems to be enforced at a pretty low level. I've updated the answer to include an nbsp on the end.